# How can I access elements in a NSDictionary which has no key?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I am doing a GET request to fill a NSDictionary. I fill that dictionary with the traditional NSJSONSerialization. I can print it, it gets all the values I wanted. However, I can't iterate or access a value in that NSDictionary, I always get a 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.

This is what I get when I print the dictionary :

```
(
        {
        "children_type" = category;
        code = realestate;
        leaf = 0;
        locales =         {
            "children_type" = category;
            code = "real estate";
        };
        parent = "";
        price = 0;
    }
)
```

(It has more value but I put here only the first one).
How can I access those element, if for example I wante to print the code (which is "realestate" here) ? I get the errors when doing a [dictionary allkeys] or [dictionary allvalues],or even a [dictionary objectForKey:]

Thank you !

Comment: There's no such thing as a dictionary with a value but no key.  Your json is an array that has 1 object which is a dictionary.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can access this dictionary ? Can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level object in that JSON data is an array, so you can enumerate it as follows:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSLog(@"children_type=%@", dict[@"children_type"]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, will mark it at resolved when I can !